# What command should be used to get text from a line of an XML file on linux?

Tags: xml, linux, bash

I have a text file and from that file i have to get specific text. What command should be used to get it?

e.g. file text is as follows:

```
<name>this is first line</name>
<name>this is second line</name>
<name>this is third line</name>
```

I have to get only text from these tags, i.e. i need "this is first line".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/<name>(.*?)<\/name>/)' file
this is first line
this is second line
this is third line
```

awk

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ RS="</name>" }/<name>/{ gsub(/.*<name>/,"");print }' file
this is first line
this is second line
this is third line
```

sed

```
$ sed -r 's|<name>(.[^>]*)</name>|\1|' file
this is first line
this is second line
this is third line
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend regexp based extraction for anything that's structured (like XML) and from the sample snippet, that's what it is.

Comment: I beg to differ. Sometimes, the requirements are simple.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that it is actually a full xml document, you might (should) prefer

```
xmllint -xpath '//name/text()' test.xml
```

Or if you want to have newlines, you can

```
xsltproc.exe trafo.xslt test.xml
```

with trafo.xslt like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//name[text()]">
            <xsl:if test="text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'd recommend this since it actually uses the fact that this snippet might have exploitable structure.

Comment: This doesn't print newlines between the matches.

Answer (score 5):

Sehe's answer doesn't add newlines between the lines. I'd suggest using the following instead:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//name/text()' -v '.' -n  test.xml
#              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^
#              for each xpath match    |     |
#                          print the result  |
#                         followed by a newline
```

or

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//name' -v 'text()' -n  test.xml
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^
#          for each name tag       |       |
#    print the text that's inside it       |
#                         followed by a newline
```

(they behave a little differently regarding where they print newlines)

Comment: thanks for pointing me at xmlstarlet, I haven't used it before

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need all the text inside the `<name>` tags 1 line per tag.

```
grep -Po "(?<=<name>)[^<]*(?=</name>)" yourfile
```

The result will be

```
this is first line
this is second line
this is third line
```

Comment: +1, but only use this if your document isn't well-formed XML (e.g. you don't have some root tag surrounding the whole document) and you're sure there will never be attributes in the `<name>` tag and that there will never be nested tags. If you have well-formed XML, use sehe's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

[grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) will help you find the right lines.  If it is formatted regularly, maybe you can use [cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29) to remove the `<name>` tags?  If it's not, then [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) is probably the right tool for the job.

Answer (score -1):

Is this would work for you ? (not sure to understand your need) :

```
cat yourfile | grep "this is first line"
```

Comment: @Kurumi : but Draco also use cat !?! (but with a better use of grep)

Comment: if you see his edit, he passed the file to `grep` as an argument. That's how you get rid of the `cat`